# How to Move files with VBA when I have full filepath

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I'm very new to VBA.

I have a list of file names and file paths. For example, I have a file name of "More tutorials.xlsx" and a file path of "C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Coding\VBA\More tutorials.xlsx" which is where the aforementioned file is saved.

I want to move all the files in this list to another directory. Using either one or both of the above pieces of information that I have, could someone please show me how to do this? I realise it's very simple.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Name` command. Example:

```
name "C:\temp\test.txt" as "c:\testdir\test.txt"
```

This just moved the file test.txt from my temp folder to my testdir folder on C drive.

Now you can use that to loop through the rows using something like

```
For each cell in range("A1:A" & range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row)
    'Do your moving of files using cell.text to get the dir
Next
```